# How to stay at the same page after submitting post request with Express?

Tags: javascript, express

I know this might be a simple question but I just didn't find the solution I want. I write a post route with express. like this:

```js
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
    // Some code to get data from req and save data to db
    // Then want to stay current page.
});
```

My html:

```html
<form action="/search" method="post">
     <input value="name" name="marker[name]">
     <input value="address" name="marker[address]">
     <input value="rating" name="marker[rating]">

     <button id="favo-button" type="submit">
         Submit
     </button>
 </form>
```

When user click submit button, the data sent through req to the post route, and there insert to db. Then I want the page not direct to anywhere but stay current page. I tried some ways but not handle it very well. what I tried:

1. in the route,

```js
res.render('/search');
```

this makes the page re-render with the same view, but the page will flash because of the re-render.

2. don't do anything to the res in the route, then the page loading circle will never stop.

```js
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
    var data = req.body.marker;
    // some code insert data to db
    // then do nothing to res. The page will stay but keep loading.
});
```

Is there a way to just do nothing to `res` and stay, meanwhile not keep the page loading?

Comment: Related: _[What is AJAX and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work)_

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Return a [`204 No Content` response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204). (In Express: `app.post('/search', (req, res) => res.status(204).send());`, but that's basic HTTP you can do in any server-side code)
2. Make the request with JavaScript (i.e. Ajax, e.g. with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)) instead of submitting the form

(You could also submit the form to a hidden iframe, but that's just an ugly hack).

Comment: Hi, what if I want to stay on the same page and give an alert 'data submitted successfully' and clear the form data?@Quentin

Comment: Then pick option 2 and do the alert and clearing in JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways: 
1 - Do it using Jquery AJAX call, you need to write this code in your view page, not in controller or route of NODEJS App.

```
$("#YOUR_FORM_ID").on("submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { $("#YOUR FORM ID").serialize() },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success!')
        }
        , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            alert('text status ' + textStatus + ', err ' + err)
        }
    });
});
```

2 - By redirecting the request to the source request

```
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
   //Do Something
   res.redirect('/');//redirect to the page from where request came
});
```